# Get access to the type by its name in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby I can say (I picked up Mongoid only for example)

```
class MyItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  #.................

  def method1(some_type)
    raise "Not symbol" unless some_type.is_a?(Symbol)
    raise "Unsupported some_type (#{some_type})" unless [:some_type1, :some_type2, :some_type3].include?(some_type)
    min_time_to_update = 60*60
    full_method_name = "#{some_type}_another_method".to_sym()

    !!self.send(full_method_name)
  end
end
```

and call it

```
result = MyItem.first.method1(:some_type2)
```

Here the method `send` is being used to call a type's method by its name. But what if I want to do the following

```
  def method1(type, arg1, arg2)
     #check if it's a correct type....
     # type might be either MyItem1 or MyItem2 or anything that has a method `method123`
     "#{type}".method123(arg1, arg2)
  end
```

How can I do that? How can I get access to **the type by its name** to call its method?

Comment: What is `list_type`? What is `MyItem#first`? Explain all methods or local variables that are not standard. Also, in Ruby, the word "class" is used. Using "type" makes it difficult to immediately understand, and puts extra burden to the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` being a string eg. 'MyItem1' or 'MyItem2'?

Try `Object.const_get(type).method123(arg1, arg2)`.